# opendatacube ingestion of a Sentinel3 product

Tags: github, gis, geocoding, data-cube, sentinelsat

I would like to ingest a Sentinel 3 OLCI Level 2 product so I'm trying to make the 'prepare_dataset.py' script. I can't get the 'grid_spatial/projection' details, particularly 'geo_ref_points'. I've tried to use RasterIO, as recommended [here](https://github.com/ceos-seo/data_cube_ui/blob/master/docs/ingestion_guide.md), but when I load the '.nc' file of a band I have a 'NotGeoreferencedWarning' and I can't extract the desired information.

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Here you can find a tour that explains how to create a good question. :-)
https://stackoverflow.com/tour.
Can you provide a code example of what you have done?

Comment: Hey, this question would be better answered in [https://gis.stackexchange.com/](https://gis.stackexchange.com/).